# How to connect two string that hasn't same word

Tags: java, android, string

I am trying to connect two string that hasn't same word for matching game. I've the code that, I've create, work with same text. For example if first pick = "word1" the second pick must has same text "word1".I want first pick = "word1" and second pick = "definition1". Please help
for more details see the code below .

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    text[0] = "word1";
    text[1] = ("definition1");


    twotext[0] = "word2";
    twotext[1] = ("definition2");


    threetext[0] = "word3";
    threetext[1] = ("definition3");


    foretext[0] = "word4";
    foretext[1] = ("definition4");


    }
    public void setBoard()
    {
        board = new String[8];
        //Assigns each image to two random positions
        for(int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
        {
            int pic1 = (int)(Math.random()*board.length);
            int pic2 = (int)(Math.random()*board.length);
            int pic3 = (int)(Math.random()*board.length);
            int pic4 = (int)(Math.random()*board.length);


            while(board[pic1]!=null)
            {
                pic1 = (int)(Math.random()*board.length);
            }
            board[pic1] = text[i];


            while(board[pic2]!=null)
            {
                pic2 = (int)(Math.random()*board.length);
            }
            board[pic2] = twotext[i];



            while(board[pic3]!=null)
            {
                pic3 = (int)(Math.random()*board.length);
            }
            board[pic3] = threetext[i];


            while(board[pic4]!=null)
            {
                pic4 = (int)(Math.random()*board.length);
            }
            board[pic4] = foretext[i];





        }


        //Sets the question mark image to each ImageView and makes each clickable
        for(int i = 0; i < board.length; i++)

        {
            pics[i].setText(board[i]);

        }



        for(Button i: pics)

        {

            i.setClickable(true);
        }
    }

//If an image is clicked it will "flip" to reveal the image below
    //If the first and second pick match, 100 points are awarded, otherwise 200 are deducted
    public void click(View v){

        switch (v.getId())
        {
            case R.id.i0:
                pics[0].setText(board[0]);
                if(firstPick) pick1 = 0;
                else pick2 = 0;
                break;

            case R.id.i1:
                pics[1].setText(board[1]);
                if(firstPick) pick1 = 1;
                else pick2 = 1;
                break;

            case R.id.i2:
                pics[2].setText(board[2]);
                if(firstPick) pick1 = 2;
                else pick2 = 2;
                break;

            case R.id.i3:
                pics[3].setText(board[3]);
                if(firstPick) pick1 = 3;
                else pick2 = 3;
                break;

            case R.id.i4:
                pics[4].setText(board[4]);
                if(firstPick) pick1 = 4;
                else pick2 = 4;
                break;

            case R.id.i5:
                pics[5].setText(board[5]);
                if(firstPick) pick1 = 5;
                else pick2 = 5;
                break;

            case R.id.i6:
                pics[6].setText(board[6]);
                if(firstPick) pick1 = 6;
                else pick2 = 6;
                break;

            case R.id.i7:
                pics[7].setText(board[7]);
                if(firstPick) pick1 = 7;
                else pick2 = 7;
                break;
        }

        if(!firstPick)
        {
            pics[pick2].setClickable(false);

            if(board[pick1]==board[pick2]) {



                    matches++;
                    score += 100;
                    layout.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
                    final Handler handler = new Handler();
                    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            layout.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
                        }
                    }, 500);
                }
```

............
............

Comment: If there is no duplication in words, I recommend you to use `HashMap`. It has <key>-<value> format. So if you want to get <value>, you just input the <key>.

Comment: "matching" smth to smth means that there is injection from a set<what you are matching> to a set <to what you are matching> = there is no duplicating. You can not "match" something to 2 different things by definition.

Comment: the problem that I notice in this line "if(board[pick1]==board[pick2])" . when i choice first pick the second one must be same word. I need way to change the second word. for example "sentence"=="words" . In this code i must to keep same word in two pick like "sentence"=="sentence". thanks for helping me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for all **k**

```
            case R.id.ik:
            pics[k].setText(board[k]);
```

you set the same old text, because textof (pics[i]) = board[i]:

```
        for(int i = 0; i < board.length; i++)
    {
        pics[i].setText(board[i]);
    }
```

You said you want different match(that you predefined)

```
            case R.id.ik:
            pics[k].setText(board[matches.get(board[i])]);
```

where **matches** is your predifined matches:

```
HashMap<String, String> matches = new HashMap<String, String>();
```

and you put your matches any way you like

```
for(int i = 1; i <= 4; i++)
  matches.put("word"+i, "definition" + i);
```

Note: your code for board part is excessive, You can accomplish everything in onCreate in just a couple of lines with a much better understanding.

Comment: Hi bedbad. I made it excessive to help me to find were the problem. the problem that I notice in this line  "if(board[pick1]==board[pick2])" . when i choice first pick the second one must be same word. I need to way to change the second word. for example "sentence"=="words" . In this code i must to keep same word in two pick like "sentence"=="sentence". thanks for helping me.

Comment: well you're doing the same thing 100 times.  thats why its really hard to keep up with your code and say where is :mistake". just keep 1 list for string and another for picks and dont use while to assign 1 random number.  I can remake your code the way that this line would be completely right. the whole code is a mess honestly.

Comment: Anyway, you use
if(board[2] == matches.get(board[1]))
that will do it

Comment: thank you so much. for your advice I will change the whole code and I will let you know if that work.